# Is 'Reports List' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I am designing a dashboard. Here is the sections in the dashboard:

- Reports
- Items
- Contacts

Inside each section will be a list. I am not sure if the list below is grammatically correct since the section names above are all plural.

- Reports List
- Items List
- Contacts List

I am aware of another option which is 'List of (section name)' but this is a bit too long and is only kept as the last option.

Answer (score 1):

I create similar dashboards. I don't think it matters that much but I would allow the word "List" to do the work of the plural for each and use the singular of the categories. It is a list, or plurality, of reports so it is correct to say a Report list etc.